# Unable to read appsettings.json keys which have dots

Tags: c#, json, xml, nlog

I am trying to access appsettings.json properties into NLog.Config file. I am writing rules in nlog and accessing loglevels from appsettings using configsetting layout renderer.
It is working fine with normal properties (Microsoft), using below code

```
<logger name="Microsoft*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />
```

With properties that have dot in name (Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) I am not able to read the value

```
<logger name="Microsoft*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />
```

Json sample below:

```
 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Error"
    }
```

I tried below but nothing worked so far

```
<logger name="Microsoft*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel'.Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime'}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />
<logger name="Microsoft*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.'Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime'}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />
<logger name="Microsoft*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft\.Hosting\.Lifetime}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />
<logger name="Microsoft*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft/.Hosting/.Lifetime}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />
<logger name="Microsoft*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel'.[Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime]'}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />
```

**EDIT 1:**
Tried Rolf Kristensen's solution and it is partly working with one minor issue.
Logs are working as per loglevel set with just one minor issue.

My nlog.config file settings

```
<logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft\\.Hosting\\.Lifetime}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />
<logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*" maxlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft\\.Hosting\\.Lifetime}" writeTo="void" final="true" />
<logger name="Microsoft*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />       
<logger name="Microsoft*" maxlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft}" writeTo="void" final="true"/>
<logger name="*" minlevel="${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Default}" writeTo="logfile,Loggly" />
```

appsettings.json set

```
 "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Error",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
```

Expectation is that for `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime` rule it should push logs till and including Information level to void. But its pushing till Error level to void. I think it is picking the loglevel set for `Microsoft`.

Logs taken from nlog internal logs:

```
2022-08-25 13:09:30.7512 Warn Logger: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime configured with duplicate output to target: FileTarget(Name=logfile). LoggingRule with NamePattern='Microsoft*' and Level=Error has been skipped.
2022-08-25 13:09:30.7512 Warn Logger: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime configured with duplicate output to target: FileTarget(Name=logfile). LoggingRule with NamePattern='*' and Level=Fatal has been skipped.
2022-08-25 13:09:30.7512 Debug Targets configured when LogLevel >= Trace for Logger: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime
2022-08-25 13:09:30.7512 Debug Logger Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime [Trace] => void
2022-08-25 13:09:30.7678 Debug Logger Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime [Debug] => void
2022-08-25 13:09:30.7678 Debug Logger Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime [Info] => logfile Loggly void
2022-08-25 13:09:30.7678 Debug Logger Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime [Warn] => logfile Loggly void
2022-08-25 13:09:30.7678 Debug Logger Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime [Error] => logfile Loggly void
2022-08-25 13:09:30.7678 Debug Logger Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime [Fatal] => logfile Loggly
```

Comment: Yes right now `${configsetting}` only recognizes `dot` as default section-delimeter. You are wellcome to create a pull-request to override the default section-delimiter. Or add support for doing escape of delimiter-chars. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging

Comment: Created a pull-request: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/pull/614

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog.Extensions.Logging v5.0.2 have been released. Where you can do this:

```
${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft\\.Hosting\\.Lifetime}
```

Or you can do this:

```
${configsetting:item=Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft..Hosting..Lifetime}
```

See also: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/5.0.2

Comment: Added more details on question, its partly working. Please check!

Comment: @Balateja Think your original question has been answered, and you should start a new one. But yes NLog LoggingRules are powerful but also hard when starting to use `final="true"`. I suggest that you change from `final="true"` to use `finalMinLevel="???"` that was introduced with NLog v5 to match Microsoft Logging Filters. See also: [new finalMinLevel-option](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter)